# Method table layout in clr 4.0

Tags: debugging, c#-4.0, sos

I have tow classes Class1 and Program a shown below:

```
 class Class1
 {
     public void xx()
     { 

     }
 }

 class Program : Class1
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {

     }
 }
```

But when i see the method table i not see the inherited public functions in Program class.
Why this is happened?I think inherited methods should be present in method table program class.

Comment: please any suggestion is wel come

Comment: Make it virtual to see the difference.

Comment: thank for reply Hans,i can create the object of Program and access the method xx() of base.But now tell me how object of program locates to method xx() because it is not in its method table??????

Comment: The compiler already knows it is non-virtual so it directly generates a call to Class1.xx().  Use ildasm.exe to look at the generated IL.

Comment: OK,that mean here the address of the method xx() from Class1's method table is burn by clr and emits call to it.Here clr not required the object reference to class1's method table.......clr does it automatically...."IS IT CORRECT"